# How can I install sshpass without sudo permissions?

Tags: permissions

While trying to install sshpass, I encounter this *permission denied* issue

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c
mv -f .deps/main.Tpo .deps/main.Po
gcc -g -O2 -o sshpass main.o
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/splashbi/sshpass/sshpass-1.08'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/install -c sshpass '/usr/local/bin'
/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/sshpass’: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/splashbi/sshpass/sshpass-1.08'
make: *** [install-am] Error 2
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: We can't fix this ... You need to ask the person who does have sudo permissions.

Comment: Install to a prefix you can write to instead of `/usr/local`.

Comment: `sshpass` doesn't seem to have any dependencies. You could try to copy the binary manually to `~/bin` or `~/.local/bin`, then re-login. `sshpass` will only be available to you, though.